# How to not call context.done() twice in Azure Function when using request() and callback?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions

I'm writing an Azure Function that makes a call to a Google API using the npm module request. The callback that processes `body` needs to call `context.done()` or else `context.res` is out of scope (if I set it within the callback and then wait to use it at the end of my script through `context.done()`).

The *problem* is I'm not understanding how to both handle errors and return a response to the client *and* use the callback.

Any and all comments on my code are welcome. I want to improve.

```js
var request = require('request');

module.exports = function (context, req) {

    if (req.body) {
        incoming = req.body

        if (incoming.components && incoming.components.city
            && incoming.components.state
            && incoming.components.country) {

            // locality = city
            // administrative_area = state
            var country = incoming.components.country;
            var administrative_area = incoming.components.state;
            var locality = incoming.components.city;

            request.get({
                url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:US|locality:city|administrative_area:CA&key=..."
            }, function (error, response, body) {
                if (error) {
                    context.log(error);
                }

                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    context.log(body)
                }
                context.res = {
                    status: 200,
                    body: "asdf"
                };
                context.done();
            });

            context.log("here");
        } else {
            context.res = {
                status: 400,
                body: 'There was data but not the right kind. Try {"components": {"country": "US","city": "city","state": "CA"}'
            };
        }

    }
    else {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: 'Nothing was received. Try {"components": {"country": "US","city": "city","state": "CA"}'
        };
    }
    context.done();
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't call `context.done()` at the end of your function. Only call it when you have the result (i.e. when you detected error or inside the callback). A bit refactored and simplified version of your function:

```js
module.exports = function (context, req) {
    if (!req.body) {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: 'Nothing was received. Try {"country": "US"}'
        };
        context.done();
        return;
    }

    if (!req.body.country) {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: 'There was data but not the right kind. Try {"country": "US"}'
        };
        context.done();
        return;
    }        

    request.get({
        url: "https://www.google.com?q=" + req.body.country
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            context.log(error);
            context.res = {
                status: 500,
                body: "Unexpected error"
            };
        } else {
            if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                context.log(body)
            }
            context.res = {
                status: 200,
                body: "asdf"
            };
        }
        context.done();
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you. This makes perfect sense.

Comment: Does it? Because generating an error that way does not appear as an error in any of the monitoring tools. There doesn't appear to be a way to both generate an error AND return a custom response to the user. Azure blows.